# why using any after 'in some cases'?

Tags: grammar, expressions

The sentence is 'I make the decision not to take a lot of, or in some cases any, photographs'

Can this sentence omit the word 'any'?
After finding lots of expression online, i cannot find the answer why the word 'any' is here.

Comment: "...not to take a lot of photos, or in some cases, not to take _any_ photos".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an awkwardly formed sentence to me.

*"not to take"* makes the following expression negative. In a negative context, *any* means *no*.

It's a general rule to include *any* in such cases.

> In some cases, I don't take any photos.
> In some cases, I take no photos.
> <strike>In some cases, I don't take photos.</strike>

*not to take a lot of photos*, which you also might find confusing, means *take some/a few photos*.

Read more:

- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any
- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/negative-clauses-with-any-anybody-anyone-anything-anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The two parts of the sentence are contrasting "any" against "a lot"; the phrase "or in some cases" is connecting these two. The whole phrase "or in some cases any" is offset with commas on both sides because it is a *parenthetical* phrase: it can be removed, and the remaining sentence is still correct.

1. I make the decision not to take *a lot of* photographs (= I choose not to take many; I choose to only take a small number)
2. I make the decision not to take *any* photographs (= I choose to take no photos at all)
3. *In some cases*, I make the decision not to take any photographs (in other cases, I choose to do something different)
4. I make the decision not to take a lot of, or in some cases any, photographs (= In some cases, I only take a few photos; in other cases, I take none at all)